# asp.net sql selecting data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

[IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/2141deb.jpg[/IMG]

The image above is my 3 tables i have created and filled up with my data. I am using Visual Studio 2013, though i think with my question all details are irrelevant as it is a basic sql problem.

```
< <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectPizza %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT users.[title], users.[gname], users.[sname], users.[suburb], users.[postcode], pizzas.[type], orders.[pizza-size] orders.[quantity] 
FROM orders JOIN users ON users.[username]=orders.[username] JOIN pizzas ON pizzas.[pizza-id] = orders.[id]">
 <SelectParameters>
 <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="login_username"
 Name="username" />
 </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When i do this code i get a basic syntax error "Incorrect syntax near '.'. "
What am i doin wrong, i know since there is a hyphen in one of my column names pizza-id I decided to put braces around all of them. Any help would be grateful

Comment: This isn't [tag:asp-classic], Edward, it's ASP.NET. Perhaps you need to [read up a little](http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-26.aspx) about the differences. You'll also get more help from the [tag:asp.net] group than [tag:asp-classic]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you frogot a comma in:

```
SELECT users.[title], users.[gname], users.[sname], users.[suburb], users.[postcode], pizzas.[type], orders.[pizza-size] orders.[quantity]
```

between `orders.[pizza-size]` and `orders.[quantity]`

```
    SELECT u.title, u.gname, u.sname, u.suburb, u.postcode, p.type, o.pizza-size, o.quantity 
      FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.username=o.username 
INNER JOIN pizzas p ON p.pizza-id = o.id
```

and remove the `[]`

Comment: There also seem to be a leading `<` at the very beginning of the data source, though this probably is harmless.

Comment: i think this a copy & paste error... because the Error is:  "Incorrect syntax near '.'. "

Comment: thankyou Paul, i knew it was probably something small i overlooked, appreciate your help